# Add a field in sf_guard_user

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm using Symfony1.4 on a website. We are recasting it under Laravel5. Both versions are currently online and share the same database. We are using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin.

We added an integer field in sf_guard_user. It works fine in Laravel but we can't access its value under Symfony1.4.
(I know we are not supposed to use directly sf_guard_user, but we have to stick with it for now, as SF1.4 version is going offline in a few weeks).

We added the field to the schema.yml, and a getter in the model (sfGuardUser.class.php).

Is there anything else we need to do in order to access the value of the field ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating schema.yml should be enough, provided you also regenerate classes: `./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`

New field is not accessible directly on `sfContext::getInstance->getUser()`, but on returned guard user:

```
sfContext::getInstance->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getAdditionalField()
```